# Cargar javascript después de la carga del DOM

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy optimizando la velocidad de carga de mi página, pero me encuentro en el problema de un javascript bloqueante.

Quiero cargar un javascript que es el que controla la mayor cantidad de funciones de mi página de inicio, pero no logro ejecutarla después de añadirla al `<head>` con `append`.

He probado con jQuery, con javascript, pero no logro hacer que se ejecute, y eso me resta bastantes puntos en google insight (casi 50 puntos es lo que me resta).

No puedo ponerlo de manera asincrona porque no sé nada de `async` / `await`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, vendría bien saber en qué orden cargas los javascripts y si ejecutas en ellos código inmediato o si los postpones a la carga del DOM (como debería hacerse).

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso del atributo [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) de la etiqueta `<script>`:

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing `DOMContentLoaded`.

En castellano:

> **defer**
>
> Este atributo booleano se agrega para indicar a un navegador que el script debe ser ejecutado después de que el documento haya sido analizado, pero antes de iniciar `DOMContentLoaded`.

---

También puedes hacer uso del atributo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) (introducido en HTML5) de la etiqueta `<script>`:

> **async** <kbd>HTML5</kbd>
>
> For classic scripts, if the `async` attribute is present, then the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.

En castellano:

> **async** <kbd>HTML5</kbd>
>
> Para los scripts clásicos, si el atributo `async` está presente, entonces el script clásico será cargado en paralelo a la evaluación y evaluado tan pronto como esté disponible.

---

Aquí puedes ver un esquema del comportamiento de ambos atributos:

[image: https://cybmeta.com/diferencia-async-y-defer]

---

Por último, puedes usar un código como éste que se cargue tras la carga del DOM:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    /* Creamos una etiqueta "<script>" */
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    /* El atributo "src" apunta al script que deseamos cargar */
    script.src = "archivo.js";
    /* Insertamos el script en el DOM (al final del <body>) */
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Intente con async, pero no me ejecuta el script, es un script grande, de medio mega, pero es el script principal de toda mi página, tambien probe con el defer, pero me lo sigue marcando como codigo bloqueante...

respecto al script ultimo que me proporcionaste, ese se coloca al inicio o al final del documento, al inicio me refiero al <head> y al final antes del cierre del body  (</body>)

Comment: Se coloca en cualquier lado, ya que esperará a que el DOM esté listo lo pongas donde lo pongas. ¿Sería posible saber qué haces en ese Javascript? Aunque sea medio mega, estoy seguro que lo que aumenta su tamaño puede separarse, optimizarse o guardarse en el almacenamiento del navegador. ¿Es solo código o también hay datos?

Comment: Pues es que ese codigo no era mio, la pagina la trabaje con un amigo, y me di cuenta hace un momento que mi amigo metio 12 scripts en un solo js, dando el peso total de 450kb entonces ya separe los archivos, pero ahora los separe y como tengo un apartado de activar y desactivar scripts, los agregare alli y pues activare y desactivare funciones que no son necesarias, solo el script del calendario pesa 215 kbs, solo me quedan cargar 235 kbs e intentarlos cargar de manera no bloqueante.

Comment: probé también el código que me enviaste, pero no me agrega al script al documento, solamente se queda el script escrito sin mas

Comment: modifique tu codigo agregando function, de esta manera document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});
y agregando tu código, y me lo agrega al final del body, pero no me ejecuta el contenido del archivo... :c

Comment: Es código Javascript, debe ir entre las etiquetas `<script>...</script>`.

Comment: esta entre esas etiquetas

Comment: ¿Tienes la página visible en Internet para poder verla y ver en qué podría mejorarse? ¿Nos facilitas la URL?

Comment: https://sercoma.miloodp.com

Comment: Ahora mismo el recurso más grande que no es de terceras páginas es `/assets/front/js/plugin.min.js` y, como decías, está formado por la unión de múltiples archivos javascript. Pero ocupa 100k y su velocidad de carga no debería ser un problema. Simulando una red 3G rápida el DOM se carga en 8 segundos y la carga completa finaliza a los 12 segundos. Sin límite el DOM carga en 1.5 segundos y todo en 2 segundos. Si uso el método que te propongo al final el DOM carga en poco más de 4 segundos, podría ser menos si no fuera por la cantidad de fuentes que carga.

Comment: El principal problema que veo es que hay un script que no quita la señal de carga hasta que todo el contenido de la página ha sido completamente cargado, que hay más de 3 MB en imágenes y una buena parte de ellas las carga el código javascript. Creo que deberías reducir la carga de javascript y ejecutar o cargar lo que necesites. Una portada debe ser ligera, liviana, y ciertos efectos javascript pueden ser retenidos hasta después de la carga de la página.