# Sumar inputs de varias tablas de manera individual y conjunta

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy desarrollando un formulario en el que tengo 3 tablas.

Tengo que sumar los datos de cada tabla de manera individual y luego estas 3 sumas (1 por tabla) sumarlas entre sí.

Al realizar la suma de una tabla sí me lo hace, pero cuando pongo las tres no lo hace.

He probado a cambiar el script, duplicarlo y cambiar las clases de cada `<input>` de la tabla pero soy bastante nuevo en esto y la verdad que me he quedado bastante pillado, así que si alguien me puede echar un cable sería genial.

Éste es mi código:

```js
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;

    $(".txt").each(function() {

      var value = $(this).text();
 
if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
    sum += parseFloat(value);
}});

    
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <table border="1" class="colapsado">
            <caption class="titulos"> Predisposición genética </caption>
           
            <tr class="modo1"> 
                <th> Puntuación </th>
                <th> 0 </th>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
                <th> 4 </th>
                <th> puntos </th>
              
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <th> ¿Cuál es el color de sus ojos? </th>
                <td> Azul claro, verde, gris</td>
                <td> Azul, gris o verde</td>
                <td> Azul </td>
                <td> Marron oscuro</td>
                <td> Negro </td>
                <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Cuál es el color natural de su pelo? </th>
                <td> Rojizo</td>
                <td> Rubio</td>
                <td> Castaño, Rubio oscuro </td>
                <td> Marron oscuro</td>
                <td> Negro </td>
                <td>  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Cuál es el color de su piel(áreas no expuestas? </th>
                <td> Rojizo</td>
                <td> Muy pálido</td>
                <td> pálido con tinte beige </td>
                <td> Marron clara</td>
                <td> Marron oscura</td>
                <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Tiene pecas en las áreas no expuestas? </th>
                <td> Muchas </td>
                <td> Algunas </td>
                <td> Pocas </td>
                <td> Accidental </td>
                <td> No </td>
                <td>  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                 </tr>
                     <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por predisposición genética: </td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
                
        </table>
     <br/>
    
         <table border="1" class="colapsado">
             <caption> Reacción a la exposición al sol </caption>
            
             <tr class="modo1"> 
                <th> Puntuación </th>
                <th> 0 </th>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
                <th> 4 </th>
                <th> puntos </th>
              
              
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <th> ¿Qué ocurre cuando se expone al sol mucho tiempo? </th>
                <td> Enrojecimiento doloroso, ampollas, desescamación </td>
                <td> Ampollas seguidas de peeling </td>
                <td> A veces me quemo y después me pelo </td>
                <td> Rara vez me quemo </td>
                <td> Nunca me he quemado </td>
                 <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿En qué medida se broncea? </th>
                <td> Muy difícil o nunca </td>
                <td> Bronceado ligero </td>
                <td> Bronceado razonable  </td>
                <td> Bronceado muy fácil </td>
                <td> Muy bronceado muy rápido </td>
               <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>

                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Se broncea después de varias horas de exposición al sol? </th>
                <td> Nunca</td>
                <td> Rara vez </td>
                <td> a veces </td>
                <td> A menudo </td>
                <td> Siempre </td>
               <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>

                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Como reacciona su cara al sol? </th>
                <td> Muy sensible </td>
                <td> Sensible </td>
                <td> Normal </td>
                <td> Muy resistente </td>
                <td> Nunca he tenido problemas </td>
                <td >  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
  
                 </tr>
                      <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por Reacción a la exposición al sol :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
                          
                 
         </table>
     
                  <table border="1" class="colapsado">
                      <caption> hábitos de bronceado </caption>
           
            <tr class="modo1"> 
                   <th> Puntuación </th>
                <th> 0 </th>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
                <th> 4 </th>
                <th> puntos </th>
              
              
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <th> ¿Cuándo tomó el sol por última vez (o lámpara UVA o crema autobronceadora? </th>
                <td> Hace más de 3 meses</td>
                <td> hace 2-3 meses </td>
                <td> Hace 1-2 meses  </td>
                <td> Hace menos de 1 mes</td>
                <td> Hace menos de 2 semanas </td>
                <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
<br/>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                <th> ¿Expuso el área a tratar al sol? </th>
                <td> Nunca</td>
                <td> Casi nunca</td>
                <td> A veces </td>
                <td> A menudo </td>
                <td> Siempre </td>
                <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"   /></td>
   
                
                 </tr>
               <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por hábitos de bronceado: </td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
                                                      
                  </table>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jQuery usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que diferencies de alguna forma cada uno de los bloques para poder hacer las sumas parciales.

Puedes hacerlo, por ejemplo, haciendo uso del atributo `name` de los `<input>`:

```
<input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1" />
```

Además, debes diferenciar también el elemento donde mostrarás los resultados parciales. Te recomiendo que su `id`, por ejemplo, coincida con los `name` que anteriormente hemos agrupado:

```
<span id="txt1">0</span>
```

De modo que todos los `<input>` de la primera tabla compartirán el mismo `name` (`txt1`) y su resultado tendrá ese identificador y los de la segunda y tercera tabla tendrán `txt2` y `txt3` respectivamente.

Por último, necesitas sumar los resultados parciales para mostrar el resultado total, también con su propio `id` que lo diferencie del resto:

```
Total del todo: <td align="center"><span id="txt">0</span></td>
```

En el código explico cómo sumo los resultados de cada tabla de manera independiente y cómo hago la suma total.

Tienes un ejemplo funcionando a continuación:

```js
/* Esperamos a que el DOM se genere para agregar el manipulador de eventos */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", evento => {
  /* Buscamos todos los "input" */
  document.querySelectorAll(".txt").forEach(elemento => {
    /* Llamamos a calculateSum facilitando el valor de "name" */
    elemento.addEventListener("keyup", evento => {
      calculateSum(elemento.name);
    })
  });
});

/* Ahora tenemos el campo "name" como parámetro */
function calculateSum(name) {
  /* La matriz "sum" tendrá las sumas parciales y "total" el total */
  let sum = {}, total = 0;
  /* Iteramos todos los "input" */
  document.querySelectorAll(".txt").forEach(elem => {
    /* Convierto su valor en float y lo trato si no es NaN */
    const value = parseFloat(elem.value);
    if (isNaN(value) === false) {
      /* Si no existía la suma de ese grupo, la creamos */
      if (sum.hasOwnProperty(elem.name)) {
        sum[elem.name] += value;
      } else {
        sum[elem.name] = value;
      }
    }
  });
  /* Por cada grupo, mostramos el resultado en su "id" y calculamos el total */
  for (const tipo in sum) {
    window[tipo].innerText = sum[tipo];
    total += sum[tipo];
  }
  /* Mostramos el total (txt = window["txt"]) */
  txt.innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="colapsado">
  <caption class="titulos"> Predisposición genética </caption>
  <tr class="modo1"> 
    <th> Puntuación </th>
    <th> 0 </th>
    <th> 1 </th>
    <th> 2 </th>
    <th> 3 </th>
    <th> 4 </th>
    <th> puntos </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Cuál es el color de sus ojos? </th>
    <td> Azul claro, verde, gris</td>
    <td> Azul, gris o verde</td>
    <td> Azul </td>
    <td> Marron oscuro</td>
    <td> Negro </td>
    <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Cuál es el color natural de su pelo? </th>
    <td> Rojizo</td>
    <td> Rubio</td>
    <td> Castaño, Rubio oscuro </td>
    <td> Marron oscuro</td>
    <td> Negro </td>
    <td>  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Cuál es el color de su piel(áreas no expuestas? </th>
    <td> Rojizo</td>
    <td> Muy pálido</td>
    <td> pálido con tinte beige </td>
    <td> Marron clara</td>
    <td> Marron oscura</td>
    <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Tiene pecas en las áreas no expuestas? </th>
    <td> Muchas </td>
    <td> Algunas </td>
    <td> Pocas </td>
    <td> Accidental </td>
    <td> No </td>
    <td>  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt1"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por predisposición genética: </td>
    <td align="center"><span id="txt1">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
    
<table border="1" class="colapsado">
  <caption> Reacción a la exposición al sol </caption>
  <tr class="modo1"> 
    <th> Puntuación </th>
    <th> 0 </th>
    <th> 1 </th>
    <th> 2 </th>
    <th> 3 </th>
    <th> 4 </th>
    <th> puntos </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Qué ocurre cuando se expone al sol mucho tiempo? </th>
    <td> Enrojecimiento doloroso, ampollas, desescamación </td>
    <td> Ampollas seguidas de peeling </td>
    <td> A veces me quemo y después me pelo </td>
    <td> Rara vez me quemo </td>
    <td> Nunca me he quemado </td>
    <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt2"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿En qué medida se broncea? </th>
    <td> Muy difícil o nunca </td>
    <td> Bronceado ligero </td>
    <td> Bronceado razonable  </td>
    <td> Bronceado muy fácil </td>
    <td> Muy bronceado muy rápido </td>
    <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt2"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Se broncea después de varias horas de exposición al sol? </th>
    <td> Nunca</td>
    <td> Rara vez </td>
    <td> a veces </td>
    <td> A menudo </td>
    <td> Siempre </td>
    <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt2"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Como reacciona su cara al sol? </th>
    <td> Muy sensible </td>
    <td> Sensible </td>
    <td> Normal </td>
    <td> Muy resistente </td>
    <td> Nunca he tenido problemas </td>
    <td >  <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt2"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por Reacción a la exposición al sol :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="txt2">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
     
<table border="1" class="colapsado">
  <caption> hábitos de bronceado </caption>
  <tr class="modo1"> 
    <th> Puntuación </th>
    <th> 0 </th>
    <th> 1 </th>
    <th> 2 </th>
    <th> 3 </th>
    <th> 4 </th>
    <th> puntos </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Cuándo tomó el sol por última vez (o lámpara UVA o crema autobronceadora? </th>
    <td> Hace más de 3 meses</td>
    <td> hace 2-3 meses </td>
    <td> Hace 1-2 meses  </td>
    <td> Hace menos de 1 mes</td>
    <td> Hace menos de 2 semanas </td>
    <td>   <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt3"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ¿Expuso el área a tratar al sol? </th>
    <td> Nunca</td>
    <td> Casi nunca</td>
    <td> A veces </td>
    <td> A menudo </td>
    <td> Siempre </td>
    <td> <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt3"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Puntuación total por hábitos de bronceado: </td>
    <td align="center"><span id="txt3">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Total del todo: <td align="center"><span id="txt">0</span></td>
```

PD: No se necesita jQuery para realizar este trabajo.

Comment: Veo que aquí funciona, pero a la hora de implementarlo no sé muy bien que tengo y que no tengo que cambiar, y no consigo que funcione a la hora de ejecutarlo, y no tengo idea de el porqué, ¿podría explicarme algo más si es tan amable? Gracias

Comment: Por supuesto, solo tienes que leer detenidamente la explicación que doy antes de exponer el código. Voy a editar el código para agregar algún ejemplo que te ayude a comprender mis palabras.

Comment: Si, si entiendo el porqué lo haces, per luego a la hora de intentar implementarlo soy incapaz de saber donde va qué, pero gracias de todos modos. Uso el Jquery porque me recomendaron hacerlo así ya que en teoría es "más fácil", pero podría llevarlo a cabo de otra manera, pero ahí si que no tengo ni idea del cómo.  Seguiré intentando hacerl, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué te ocurre cuando tratas de usar el código que te proporcioné? ¿A qué te refieres con que no sabes dónde va qué?

Comment: A la hora de usarlo, no hace nada, si lo ejecuto aquí funciona perfectamente, a la hora de copiarlo ya no funciona

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir en algún servicio como gist, mega, drive, onedrive, etc el código de tu HTML? Me gustaría ver cómo lo estás intentando hacer para ayudarte y explicarte qué te está pasando.

Comment: Te le dejo aquí:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tDq5yCCm5FfAJ7vedO_tsCvjR2cBAveQ?usp=sharing

Comment: Vale, estás cometiendo un error muy común. El código JavaScript debería ir al final del documento para que el DOM se haya generado. Puedes leer una explicación en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/361871/18608 . Voy a editar mi pregunta para reflejar una solución en la que espero a que el DOM esté generado antes de agregar el manipulador de eventos a los `<input>`.

Comment: Por cierto, te recomiendo que huyas de jQuery. En sus días fue una herramienta muy útil para combatir las diferencias entre los navegadores, pero hoy en día esas diferencias son nulas (o mínimas), por lo que es mejor aprender JavaScript sin apoyarse en bibliotecas de funciones que te hagan aprender cosas que no son estándar del lenguaje (y que no podrás usar si luego deseas aprender a programar en el lado del servidor con Node.js, o en el lado del cliente con marcos de trabajo como Angular.io, etc).

Comment: Tomo nota, muchísimas gracias por todo